# More concise ruby block syntax, e.g.: `[1, 2].each { puts _ }` instead of `[1, 2].each { |i| puts i }`

Tags: ruby

So, yes, is there a way to have something like

```
[1, 2].each { puts _ }
```

Instead of

```
[1, 2].each  { |i| puts i }
```

And maybe:

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 }.each { puts _1, _2 }
```

Obviously those are simple examples, but it would much easier to write some scripts with those.

Maybe an extension for those like `def _1; ...; end` would be easier for now, but I don't see a way to get the current object being passed to the block.

Comment: out of curiosity, why does the current syntax bug you?

Comment: Given `[[1, 2], [3, 4]].each { _.each { ... } }` – how could the inner block (`...`) refer to the outer `_`?

Answer (score 4):

This is the only thing I could find

```
puts_m = method(:puts)
[1, 2, 3].each(&puts_m)
1
2
3
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what @Jan also told me: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33731398#33731398, e.g.: `[].each(&:method(:puts)` which is quite good already for some cases

Comment: you have a typo: he suggested `[].each(&method(:puts)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ursus answer!

For this case you can:

```
puts [1, 2].join "\n"
```

and you can also play with monkeypatching:

```
class Array
  def putseach
    each { |i| puts i }
  end
end
```

and call it with

```
[1, 2].putseach
```

probably not recommended in larger code bases but a fun way to get cleaner code in some cases.